# Fastest method to find the greatest length across a blob

Tags: image-processing, aforge

Using the BlobCounterBase.GetObjectInformation, I can retrieve the blobs from an image.  What is the fastest method for finding the largest length across the blob?  It is not simply the hypotenuse of the blob's Rectangle.

I can extract all of the edge points (using the GetBlobsEdgePoints method), calculate the length between every pair of edge points and find the maximum length. But this method is slow, especially when I am working with images that can have thousands of blobs.

Comment: Maybe [look at this technique](http://www.cb.uu.se/~cris/blog/index.php/archives/408) as an alternative?

Comment: Thanks, Roger. The Convex Hull idea reminded me that Aforge has a GrahamConvexHull class.  Using that, I was able to dramatically reduce the number of points I had to compare to find the largest distance across the blob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that works pretty fast for my application (thanks again to Roger Rowland for his suggestion that led to the solution):

```
    private double GetGreatestLength(Blob blob)
    {
        try
        {
            GrahamConvexHull hullFinder = new GrahamConvexHull();

            var hullPoints = hullFinder.FindHull(_blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blob));
            var maxPoints = GetMaxPoints(hullPoints);

            return maxPoints.distance * _micronsPerPixel;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    struct MaxPoints
    {
        public IntPoint firstPoint;
        public IntPoint secondPoint;
        public double distance;

        public MaxPoints(IntPoint first, IntPoint second, double dist)
        {
            this.firstPoint = first;
            this.secondPoint = second;
            this.distance = dist;
        }
    }

    private MaxPoints GetMaxPoints(IEnumerable<IntPoint> points)
    {
        var data = from a in points
                   from b in points
                   select new MaxPoints(a, b, GetDistance(a, b));

        double maxDistance = data.Max(d => d.distance);

        return data.First(d => d.distance == maxDistance);
    }

    private double GetDistance(IntPoint a, IntPoint b)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((a.X - b.X), 2) + Math.Pow((a.Y - b.Y), 2));
    }
```